# Show that all coefficients in a recursively defined function are integers

Tags: equation-solving

[Problem 2 in the 2017 Putnam exam is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bumjI-7Pz_c):

Let $Q_0(x) = 1$, $Q_1(x) = x$, and $Q_n(x) = \frac{Q_{n-1}^2(x) - 1}{Q_{n-2}(x)}$.

**Show that $Q_n(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\ \forall n \geq 0$.**

(Recall that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ denotes the set of all polynomials in $x$ with integer coefficients.)

We can define the function recursively:

```
q[0, x] = 1;
q[1, x] = x;
q[n_Integer, x_] := (q[n - 1, x]^2 - 1)/q[n - 2, x];
```

We can confirm that the first 10 (or indeed any number) of terms contains only integer-valued coefficients by:

```
IntegerQ /@ 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[CoefficientList[
    FullSimplify@Table[q[i, x], {i, 0, 10}], 
    x]]]
```

However, we want to prove the relation for *all* $n$.

We can follow the steps in the linked video, but that does not exploit *Mathematica*'s simplification or other functionality.  I've tried to use functionality to isolate `q[n,x]` in terms of `q[n-1,x]` and `q[n-2,x]` and then argue that because $Q_0(x)$ and $Q_1(x)$ are both in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then so are $Q_n(x)$ for all $n \geq 2$, but have found no clever way other than (essentially) performing the algebra "by hand."

Thanks to @Adam's suggestion, I used `FindSequenceFunction` and found that the expression was

$$\frac{2^{-n} \left(2^n-(2 x-2)^n\right)}{x-2}$$

which gets closer, but still not quite there.

Any suggestions on an elegant, *computational* approach?

Comment: The most 'elegant:MMA' approach is, I think, to find/type the closed form for $q$ (leveraging `FindSequenceFunction` if desired) and have MMA verify that it satisfies the recursion.  The most 'elegant:math' approach is almost certainly different.  The ideal 'elegant:computational' approach would be some proof assistant which could generate a proof automatically, or minify a proof (perhaps generated by MMA).

Comment: further simplify the  expression you got from `FindSequenceFunction`:  `FullSimplify[(2^n - (-2 + 2*x)^n)/(2^n*(-2 + x)), x == 1 + y]` to get `-((-1 + y^n)/(-1 + y))`.

Comment: @kglr:  Sure...thanks... but how does one know to search for $x = 1 + y$?  And how does one implement the well-known fact that $(y-1)|(y^n - 1)$ so we can simplify for *arbitrary* $n$?

Comment: Just to be clear, please give us a simple example of what you can do with Mathematica that you consider to be a "elegant, computational approach" because we don't know what you mean.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork seems you want to see more abstractions in Mathematica that allow you to handle a wider class of problems without much in the way of human insight. Unfortunately, while we may be able to create solvers for certain classes of popular problems, there are infinite problems. But worse, the sorts of quirky problems in these exams are more likely to be deliberately designed to lean on insight / 'leaps of faith' - not to be solved through mechanical applications of common rules. Mathematica won't ever be generic enough to select the right 'insight' to use in every exam problem.

Comment: @flinty:  I contend that symbol manipulation systems already solve a wider range of problems than can ever be done by hand, but most importantly are developing faster—indeed *far* faster—than is hand calculation.  Yes, there are problems better addressed by hand than by computer, and likely always will be some.  The problems in sophomore math are likely better solved algorithmically, though.  I'm focusing on contest math problems to push the limits.  Example:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253744/optimization-of-the-denominator-in-a-rational-number-under-constraints

Answer (score 5):

You asked

> Any suggestions on an elegant, *computational* approach?

It is not clear what you mean by that. Since this was a
**Putnam** problem, the elegant approach would be to
observe that
$\,Q_n(x)=U_n(x/2)\,$ where $\,U_n\,$ is the Chebyshev polynomial
of the second kind since it satisfies the same initial values
and given recursion **and** a linear recursion.

You can use Mathematica to verify the recursion with

```
U[n, x] U[n - 2, x] == U[n - 1, x]^2 - 1 /. {U -> ChebyshevU}
// FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
```

and to verify that they satisfy a specific **linear** recursion

```
U[n, x] == 2 x U[n - 1, x] - U[n - 2, x] /. {x -> Cos@t, U -> ChebyshevU}
 // FunctionExpand // Simplify
```

This recursion can be *used* to easily **prove** by
induction the result required.

Suppose we **don't** know about Chebyshev polynomials.
We observe that the first few $\,Q_n\,$ are polynomials
of degree $\,n\,$ and guess that they satisfy a linear
recursion relation. Find that linear recursion using
the code

```
ClearAll[Q0, Q1, Q];
Q[0] = Q0; Q[1] = Q1;
Q[n_Integer] := Q[n] = Expand@Simplify[(Q[n - 1]^2 - 1)/Q[n - 2]];
With[{rec = Q[n + 2] == a Q[n + 1] + b Q[n] + c}, 
  rec /. First@Solve[Table[rec, {n, 0, 2}], {a, b, c}]] // InputForm
(* Q[2+n]==-Q[n]-((1-Q0^2-Q1^2)*Q[1+n])/(Q0*Q1) *)
```

and proceed by induction as before. Note that in our
specific case of $\,Q_0=1,\,Q_1=x\,$ the coefficient of $\,Q_{n+1}\,$ is $\,x.$ Note that the coefficient in
general is `(1 - Q0^2 - Q1^2)/(Q0*Q1)` and that

```
With[{a = (1 - Q0^2 - Q1^2)/(Q0*Q1)}, 
      a == (a /. {Q0 -> Q1, Q1 -> Q[2]}) // Simplify]
```

returns `True` which verifies the linear recursion is
true for all $\,n.$

Comment: Nice insight ($+1$), but "observe that" is the kind of "human insight" I'm hoping to avoid.  I'm always asking myself:  "What does using computer algebra *really* help in these problems?"  In some problems it is clear and obvious.  Apparently not so this problem... or at least nobody has shown a computational method forward.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Please give us a simple example or two of "some problems" where Mathematica _really_ helps because it is not clear to me. The problem is asking for a proof. Mathematica is not designed to provide proofs.

Comment: I'm writing a book on this subject and plan to teach a university course on this subject and have over 100 problems where *Mathematica*'s symbol manipulation solves problems immensely faster and easier than calculations "by hand."  Here's one I posted last night:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253744/optimization-of-the-denominator-in-a-rational-number-under-constraints

Comment: @Somos Agreed, I don't think it's reasonable to expect computer algebra systems to solve these problems with one or two functions unintelligently applied to some expressions. There are things like mathlib - libraries of organized formally specified proofs and definitions that act as footholds for a proof _assistant_ / _interactive prover_ like Lean or Coq. Encode it formally and you may be able to solve it - but the point is that's very hard work to specify correctly and still relies on human insight. The search space for provers is so large that these _leaps of faith_ are often necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I present this as a way to simulate the approach to solving  the problem rather than a *computer proof*. I accept this may not be the intention. Further, I do not believe it is as nice as the video approach.

```
r[{x_, y_}, n_] := 
  Expand@*Simplify /@ 
   NestList[{#[[2]], (#[[2]]^2 - 1)/#[[1]]} &, {x, y}, n][[All, 1]];
CoefficientList[#, x, 11] & /@ r[{1, x}, 10] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}] &
ex0 = FindSequenceFunction[r[{1, x}, 5], n]
ex1 = FullSimplify[
   RSolve[{u[0] == 1, u[1] == x, u[n] == x u[n - 1] - u[n - 2]}, u, 
     n][[1, 1, 2, 2]]];
ex2 = Together[ex1 /. n -> n - 1]
ex2 === ex0
```

[image]

The table provides material for insight that $q_n= x q_{n-1}-q_{n-2}, q_0=1,q_1=x$.
`ex2` is the closed form solution for this recursion.
`ex0` is the closed form for the recursion: $q_n=\frac{q_{n-1}^2-1}{q_{n-2}}$
`ex0===ex2` establishes they are the same and from `ex2` the inference of integer coefficients (i.e. $q_n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$) as per the video (and the insight from the table entries suggest).

The inductive approach in the video seems much simpler and avoids trying to solve recursive relation. It was achievable in under 10 minutes (after calculation of some of the polynomials).

Mathematica could be used to do the algebraic manipulations for the inductive proof. I have not illustrated this.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion lies somewhere in between those of David Stork and Somos -- I often find Mathematica quite useful even for problems like these.  That being said, I don't find it useful to the extent that it generates insight.  Insight always seems comes from me or the documentation.

I'll outline the 'least inspired' approach I can come up with:

- compute 100 terms of the recursion, `Apart`ing at each step
- guess the common closed form for the sequences $\{x^i$th coefficient of $Q_n\}_{i=0}^n$.
- verify that this closed form is correct

Let's carry this out.

```
q[0]=1;q[1]=x;
q[n_]:= (q[n] = Apart[(q[n-1]^2-1)/q[n-2]] )
```

I'm memoizing the `q` so that computation only happens once.  I'm assuming that the `q` will be polynomials and hoping `Apart` will handle it well (without it the expressions would get hideous).  Not too egregious.

Now look at `Grid[CoefficientList[q@#,x]&/@Range[0,10]]`

```
1
0   1
-1  0   1
0   -2  0   1
1   0   -3  0   1
0   3   0   -4  0   1
-1  0   6   0   -5  0   1
0   -4  0   10  0   -6  0   1
1   0   -10 0   15  0   -7  0   1
0   5   0   -20 0   21  0   -8  0   1
-1  0   15  0   -35 0   28  0   -9  0   1
```

I'll get rid of the pesky `0`'s

```
1
    1
-1      1
    -2      1
1       -3      1
    3       -4      1
-1      6       -5      1
    -4      10      -6      1
1       -10     15      -7      1
    5       -20     21      -8      1
-1      15      -35     28      -9      1
```

There is tremendous structure here that would not be so obvious to someone doing back-of-the-envelope calculations during the Putnam (and I only cut it off at 10 to save screen space).

First, we assume that `q@n` is degree `n` and only has odd/even powers of $x$, according to `n` being odd/even.  This is a slightly egregious.

The actual numbers reek of binomial coefficients.  The $x^{n-2}$th coefficient of `q@n` really looks like $-\binom{n-1}1$.  Come to think of it, the $x^{n-4}$th coefficient looks like $\binom{n-2}2$.  Can it be so simple?

Let's see.  Making explicit the divinely inspired formula:

```
conjec[n_]:=Sum[x^i(-1)^((n-i)/2)Binomial[(n+i)/2,i],{i,Mod[n,2],n,2}]
```

As expected, `conjec@#-q@#&/@Range[0,100]` yields a list of `0`'s.  This is not a proof though.  I struggle to get Mathematica to verify that

```
conjec[n+2]==(conjec[n+1]^2-1)/conjec[n]
```

although I suspect it is possible.  It can certainly do so for particular `n`.

---

Comparing to Somos' approach, this involves more leaps of faith.  I'm just showing how I believe Mathematica to be most useful -- how to acquire the inspiration less divinely and more computationally.

It may be possible to exploit `FindSequenceFunction` or other MMA capabilities to offload some thinking.  For instance

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[FindSequenceFunction[CoefficientList[q@29, x]]@x, 
                    Assumptions -> x \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
Out[1]= -(1/(638512875 Gamma[(1 + x)/2])) 2^(-25 - x) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
x (2 + x) (4 + x) (6 + x) (8 + x) (10 + x) (12 + x)
  (14 + x) (16 + x) (18 + x) (20 + x) (22 + x) (24 + x) 
  (26 + x) (28 + x) ((-1)^x (-15 + C[1]) - C[1]) Pochhammer[-14, -1 + x/2]
```

And the example of `q@29` is not cherry picked; many `q`'s are of this `Pochhammer`/`Gamma` form, many `q`'s are given up on, many `q`'s are given boringly as a `DifferenceRoot`.  The problem then boils down into finding a common closed form among these... And the choice to find forms for `CoefficientList[q@n,x]` was arbitrary too -- why not go with sequences of fixed $x^i$ or fixed $x^{n-i}$?

---

All of math involves creating a guess, then verifying that guess.  In the case of competition problems, there always exists a slick way of verifying a certain kind of guess, and it's quite interesting to see how people come up with it (or in rare cases circumvent it).  In school the solution may be posed already, and the task is to simply verify it.

It might be true that fewer larger leaps of faith are equivalent to many small leaps of faith in problem-solving-capability.  Computers are certainly capable of carrying out such assumptions (computer algebra systems) and even conjecturing them (search through mathematical-statement-space).  Mathematica, unfortunately, is too weak to make the *whole* journey in this case (IMO).