# Finding all solutions to coupled algebraic equations without exhaustive enumeration

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations, findinstance

A [Cambridge University mathematics interview question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Frvj80ud5RU&list=RDCMUCT-QRRiYoza5rRDCKNdYdhg&index=16) states:

Find all $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$a + b + c = d \cdot e \cdot f$$

and

$$d + e + f = a \cdot b \cdot c$$

(There are a number of similar questions on this site, but none that concentrate on finding *all* solutions, particularly when permutations expand the solution search space.)

It is easy and fast to find one solution:

```
FindInstance[
            {a + b + c == d e f, 
             d + e + f == a b c, 
             {a, b, c, d, e, f} > 0},
 {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers]
```

(* {{a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> 1, d -> 2, e -> 3, f -> 1}} *)

Of course this solution (and others, below) can be permuted to find additional (equivalent) solutions.

The full solution set, however, is:

$\{ (3,2,1), (3,2,1) \}, \{ (1,1,6), (2,2,2) \}, \{ (1,1,8), (1,2,5) \}, \{ (1,1,7), (1,3,3) \}$ (and, of course, permutations).

I have been unable to algorithmically find all these solutions.  I've tried using `Solve`, `Reduce`, and the obvious alterations to `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[
            {a + b + c == d e f, 
             d + e + f == a b c},
            {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers,4]
```

which yields *one* additional solution, but not all four.

I've tried to reduce the solution search space by constraining (without loss of generality) the permutations of each subset of variables:

```
FindInstance[
            {a + b + c == d e f, 
             d + e + f == a b c, 
             a >= b >= c > 0, 
             d >= e >= f > 0, (a != d) \[Or] (b != e) \[Or] (c != f)},
 {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers]
```

One can also impose the fact that not all terms $\{a,b,c \}$ or $\{ d,e,f \}$ can be greater than 2.

The best I've found is:

```
FindInstance[
 {a + b + c == d e f,
  d + e + f == a b c,
  {a, b, c, d, e, f} > 0,
  a >= b >= 2 >= c > 0,
  d >= e >= f > 0,
  a != f ,
  a b  > 4 ,
  c == 1},
 {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers, 4]
```

There are yet other constraints, but none have yielded all the solutions.

I am explicitly *NOT* interested in any method that relies on exhaustive enumeration and testing, as might be implemented in *Python* or other languages without symbol manipulation.  Such methods scale poorly with number of equations, variables, upper limits, and so on.  After all, how do you know ahead of time that your numerical search need not go to, say, $10^{10}$ for each variable?!  And how can such simulation ever show that there is *NO* solution?  Or the total number of solutions that *do* exist?  The "human intelligence" in the attached link at the top is the kind of "smarts" I want to implement and exploit in *Mathematica*.

How can I compute *all* the solutions (up to permutation) using *symbol manipulation*?

Comment: No.  *Natural* number:  $1,2,3,4...$

Comment: How is `FindInstance` symbol manipulation? It could be doing exhaustive search "under the hood". The documentation does not rule that out.

Comment: Simple timing tests on related problems prove that `FindInstance` does not use exhaustive search (in general).  Further, it also can compute that *no solution exists* to a certain problem where exhaustive search would take infinite time.

Comment: Truu, `FindInstance` has certain advantages and I have used it to get good results, but it has frustrating limitations which are not documented. In some cases, exhaustive search easily finds solutions when `FindInstance` can't.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork _"Such methods scale poorly..."_ Have you considered this: if $P\neq NP$ which is very likely the case, then there are problems reducible to SAT (e.g Diophantine equations like this one) that require some degree of exhaustive checking - though perhaps not exponential as some assignments can be quickly discarded (e.g in the way [DPLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) works). Broadly speaking, the consequences of $P\neq NP$ imply that there isn't some nice algorithm that can solve all variations of problems like this.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You could also do this with z3 which is an SMT solver. The $N$ in $NP$ stands for non-deterministic - i.e these tricky "_constraint satisfaction_" problems _can_ be completed in polynomial time on a non-deterministic Turing machine. I can see an analogy between a non-deterministic computer that can 'pick the right assignments' to solve a problem in polynomial time, and a human solving the problem with heuristics and "smarts", can't you? In the video, the assumptions introduced with the inequalities _are_ leaps-of-faith that don't scale to general problems.

Comment: `Reduce[{…, 10 > {a,b,c,d,e,f} > 0},…]` does not satisfy your requirements but it works on the toy problem.

Comment: A half-step in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find solutions with FindInstance and a little detour.

Regard the two onesided equations as polynoms in `a`  and determine the parameters {b,c,d,e,f} where they both have the same roots.

```
eqs = {a + b + c == d e f, d + e + f == a b c};
vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

resa = Resultant[a + b + c - d e f, -a b c + d + e + f, a]

(*   d + e + f + b c (b + c - d e f)   *)

fi = FindInstance[
      Join[{0 == resa}, {1 <= b <= c, 1 <= d <= e <= f}], {b, c, d, e, f},
      Integers, 10]

(*   FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 6 instance(s), but it was not able to prove 10 instances do not exist. >>

{{b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 5}, {b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, 
 e -> 3, f -> 3}, {b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 2, e -> 2, f -> 2}, {b -> 1, 
 c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 8}, {b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 2, 
 f -> 3}, {b -> 2, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 6}}   *)

eqs /. fi

ss = Union@
     Flatten[{{a, b, c, d, e, f} /. First@Solve[#, a]} & /@ eqs /. fi, 2];

thx = Thread[vars -> #] & /@ ss

(*   {{a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 6}, 
      {a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 3}, 
      {a -> 5, b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 8}, 
      {a -> 6, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 2, e -> 2, f -> 2}, 
      {a -> 7, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 3, f -> 3}, 
      {a -> 8, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 5}}   *)

eqs /. thx

(*   {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
       True}, {True, True}}   *)
```

Two of these solutions are permutations. this is no proof whether this are all solutions.

Comment: Oh... this is the best, and is in the *style* of solution I seek.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$). The only way it could be better is to (as you note) *prove* that there are just six solutions (up to permutation).

Answer (score 2):

This code using `Do` returns

```
DeleteDuplicates[ With[{M = 9}, 
   Reap@Do[If[a + b + c == d e f && d + e + f == a b c, 
      Sow[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}]],
       {a, 1, M}, {b, a, M}, {c, b, M},
       {d, 1, M}, {e, d, M}, {f, e, M}]][[2, 1]],
#1 == Reverse@#2 &]
```

almost immediately.
The similar version using `FindInstance`

```
DeleteDuplicates[With[{M = 9},
  {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}} /. FindInstance[
    a + b + c == d e f && d + e + f == a b c && 
    0 < a <= b <= c <= M && 0 < d <= e <= f <= M,
      {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers, 10]],
#1 == Reverse@#2 &]
```

takes over two minutes.
I find that sometimes using `Do` beats `FindInstance`
depending on the specific problem.

---

In this case, it seems that `FindInstance` has trouble
with two equations and solving one of them is indicated
as in the answer of Akku14. The following code
uses `FindInstance` with this insight. Start with the
two equations.

```
{eq1, eq2} = {a + b + c == d e f, d + e + f == a b c};
```

Solve for the variable `c` using equation 1 to get

```
solc = Solve[eq1, c][[1, 1]]
(* c -> -a - b + d e f *)
```

and substitute it into equation 2 to get

```
eq3 = eq2 /. solc
(* d + e + f == a b (-a - b + d e f) *)
```

Finding  solutions of this equation (ignoring a warning
about not being able to prove more solutions exist)
using `FindInstance` takes almost a minute

```
find = FindInstance[{eq3, 0 < a <= b, 0 < d <= e <= f},
       {a, b, d, e, f}, Integers, 9] // Quiet
(* {{a -> 1, b -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 5},
    {a -> 1, b -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 3, f -> 3},
    {a -> 1, b -> 1, d -> 2, e -> 2, f -> 2}, 
    {a -> 1, b -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 8},
    {a -> 1, b -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 3},
    {a -> 2, b -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 6}} *)
```

Apply the solution rules, restore missing values of `c`
and reshape into solution pairs

```
solpairs = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}} /. solc /. find
(* {{{1, 1, 8}, {1, 2, 5}}, {{1, 1, 7}, {1, 3, 3}},
{{1, 1, 6}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 5}, {1, 1, 8}},
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 6}}} *)
```

Finally, eliminate duplicates from swapping `{a,b,c}` and `{d,e,f}`

```
DeleteDuplicates[sort1st, #1 == Reverse@#2 &]
(* {{{1, 1, 8}, {1, 2, 5}}, {{1, 1, 7}, {1, 3, 3}},
    {{1, 1, 6}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}} *)
```

to get the four solutions (up to permutations).

Comment: Ah... while exhaustive enumeration may indeed work, I'm looking for a *symbolic* approach.  (Your core algorithm could be implemented in *Python*, for instance.)  I should have been clearer and will edit my question accordingly.  Nevertheless, thanks ($+1$).

Comment: I prefer code and principles that work *ON GENERAL PROBLEMS*, not the simple toy problems such as this.  AND on general *symbolic* problems (which too many engineers avoid).  Also, symbolic methods are more generalizable to new problems... you don't have to start a bit simulation again.  You might find this instructive:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253744/optimization-of-the-denominator-in-a-rational-number-under-constraints